# What is the difference between Jini and RMI?

Tags: java, jini

I'm new in Jini technology. I understand it is used for distributed computing or "network plug and play".
But I don't understand the difference between pure RMI and Jini.
Also, I want to understand when Jini is used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in the Wikipedia article (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jini):

> Clients can use the lookup service to retrieve a proxy object to the
>   service; calls to the proxy translate the call to a service request,
>   performs this request on the service, and returns the result to the
>   client. This strategy is more convenient than Java remote method
>   invocation, which requires the client to know the location of the
>   remote service in advance.

So basically RMI is a mechanism to perform Java calls between a client and a server that know each other. Jini adds services to lookup services from the clients, so the clients do not need to know where the servers are located beforehand.

Comment: thanks. second section of my question is: where it used? Is it died? what are alternatives for it?